# Obtaining unexpectedly large p-value (chi square)

Tags: r, p-value

i have no much experience coding nor with statistics so sorry and thank you in advance.

I'm trying to find out if two variables (living in urban or rural areas) and using medicine A or B (due to accessibility) are related. I have a data frame with many other variables and thousands of cases on which i'm doing the analysis. This is the grouped data

$data

```
           Outcome (medicine)

Predictor 1    2    Total

Urban     1412 1792  3204
Middle    885  1167  2052
Rural     485  662   1147
Total     2782 3621  6403
```

I've tried using both chisq.test, and oddsratio.wald, obtaining with both a p.value of around 0.54, thus i can't reject the Null hypothesis and should assume that both may not be related at all, nevertheless if we look at the percentages we can see that there is a trend, in which the more rural the area, the less percentage use medicine 1.

```
          % use of Total
Urban     44.07% 
Middle    43.13%  
Rural     42.28%
```

So shouldn't i be obtaining a very low (<0.05) p value? am i doing something wrong?

I've used:

```
chiurba<-chisq.test(dfbi$TIPOANTICONCEP,dfbi$DEGURBA,simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

and

```
ORurba<-oddsratio.wald(dfbi$DEGURBA,dfbi$TIPOANTICONCEP)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think something may be wrong. How do you get usages of roughly 44%, 43%. 42%? Maybe more like 50%, 32%, 18%. Am I misreading your question?

Comment: For most of the answers proposed to date — as well as for the chi-square test of association in the question — there is an assumption that Drug A and Drug B are mutually exclusive.  That is, that no one observed person can take both Drug A and Drug B.  Also that the two are exhaustive of the possibilities.  That is, that every observed person must take one drug or the other.  ...  These assumptions are unlikely to be true in the case of two drugs.  This is one of the problems when posters create hypothetical context:  the invented context is not always relevantly similar to the true case.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, the uses are roughly 44%, 43% and 42% out of the total, (485/1147 for example).

I understand the concerns about the assumptions done and the hypothetical context, but the poll (not done by me) was designed theoretically to take this into account and treats them as mutually exclusive, asking respondents to only answer in case of taking one or the other. Again, even if there are differences betwen urban and rural areas in drug use it may not be due to accessibility but other issues.

Answer (score 2):

A crude but effective way of estimating uncertainty in those kind of problems is  by taking the square root of the number of observations (which is approximately the standard deviation of a Binomial distribution).

So for example the percentage of using medicine 1 in the rural case would be estimated as

$$ \frac{485 \pm \sqrt{485}}{1147} \approx (42.3 \pm 1.9)\% $$

which is less than 1 standard deviation away from the urban case. So, despite the suggestive trend, it is not very significant.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Statistical significance is a measure for how probable the magnitude of a certain observed effect is when there would have been, in reality, no effect.

The motivation for this is that we use observations to measure some population, but our measurements have variations and do not exactly represent the true values of the population.

If certain samples are not accurate or very representative, due to statistical variations in the sampling or measurements, then we may still measure a certain effect even if there is not a true effect.

We call a measurement statistically *significant* if, assuming that there is no effect, the magnitude of an observed effect is not likely to occur due to the statistical variations.

---

So you measure some differences 44.07%, 43.13%, 42.28%.

But, for the given sample sizes there will likely be such variations and differences in a sample even if the true percentages in the population are equal.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

(1) If the question is whether total usage
is proportionately the same in Urban, Middle, and
Rural areas, then you seem to be doing the
wrong test. In R, `prop.test` shows a highly
significant difference:

```
prop.test(c(3204,2052,1147), c(6403,6403,6403), corr=F)

        3-sample test 
        for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(3204, 2052, 1147) out of c(6403, 6403, 6403)
X-squared = 1494, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
    prop 1    prop 2    prop 3 
 0.5003904 0.3204748 0.1791348
```

This is the essentially equivalent to a
chi-squared test whether counts `c(3204, 2052, 1147)` are homogeneous.

```
chisq.test((c(3204,2052,1147)))

    Chi-squared test 
    for given probabilities

data:  (c(3204, 2052, 1147))
X-squared = 996, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

When no probabilities are specified, the 'given
probabilities' are assumed to be equal.

The expected counts can be displayed as follows:

```
chisq.test((c(3204,2052,1147)))$exp
[1] 2134.333 2134.333 2134.333
```

(2) However, you are correct that usage patterns for Drugs 1 and 2
are about the same across the three types
of regions.

```
TBL = cbind(c(1412, 885,485),
            c(1792,1167,662))
TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1412 1792
[2,]  885 1167
[3,]  485  662

chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 1.2218, df = 2, 
 p-value = 0.5429
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Also you provided me tools i didn't know existed!

The question was not if total usage is proportionally the same depending on the area, as the number of respondents from every region was very different, but wheter if within each region the pattern of drug usage was the same, as you mention in the last part of your comment. 

Thank you for the answer and information!

Comment: Glad my answer helped.  // Hope you'll visit the site often. Maybe take the tour for tips on how to ask questions that yield useful answers. Also about Upvoting and/or Accepting answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about `Location` as a ordinal variable, you should probably treat it that way in the analysis.  One classic test of association that would be applicable here is the Cochran–Armitage test.  I believe this test doesn't actually treat the one variable as truly ordinal, but you have to assume the spacing between the categories.

However, since you have labeled `Location` as "Predictor" and `Drug` as "Outcome", you would want to use a model that explicitly treats one variable as the independent variable and one variable as the dependent variable.  In this case, logistic regression, using `Location` as on ordinal independent variable would work.
I tried both if these approaches with your data.  Each brings the *p*-value down to < 0.3. This is (sometimes !) the advantage of treating an ordinal variable as ordinal.

The upshot:  You do have a little bit of a trend over location, but whether or not you got a low *p*-value, and for whichever statistical approach you took, the question is really, *Is a difference between 42% and 44% for Drug A important in this context?*

I have R code for these analyses below.  I have more information on the Cochran–Armitage test at the following link, with the caveat that I wrote it. [rcompanion.org/handbook/H_09.html](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_09.html)

```
Input =(
   "Drug     A    B
Location  
Urban     1412 1792
Middle    885  1167
Rural     485  662
")

Tabla = as.table(read.ftable(textConnection(Input)))

Tabla

prop.table(Tabla,
           margin = 1)

library(coin)

spineplot(Tabla)

library(coin)

chisq_test(Tabla, scores = list("Location" = c(-1, 0, 1)))

##########################################

Data = read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Location  Drug Count
Urban     A    1412 
Middle    A     885  
Rural     A     485  
Urban     B    1792
Middle    B    1167
Rural     B     662
")

Data$Location = factor(Data$Location, 
                       levels = c("Urban", "Middle", "Rural"), ordered=TRUE)

Data$Drug = factor(Data$Drug)

library(tidyr)

Long = uncount(Data, Count)

xtabs(~ Location + Drug, data=Long)

model = glm(Drug ~ Location, data=Long, family=binomial())

summary(model)
```